Proof that the order of elements stays the same under Frobenius endomorphism
Let $E: Y^2=X^3+Ax+B$ be an elliptic curve, defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a prime. Define:
$$\phi: E(\bar{\mathbb{F}}) \rightarrow E(\bar{\mathbb{F}})$$ by
$$\phi(P) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \mathcal{O}  & \mbox{if } P = \mathcal O\\
  (x^p,y^p) & \mbox{if } P=(x,y)
 \end{array}
\right.$$
Consider a torsion group with all elements of prime order $q$ :
$$E[q]=\{P\in E(\bar{\mathbb{F}})~|~q\cdot P=\mathcal O\}\setminus\{\mathcal O\}$$
Proof that $\phi(P)$ is of order $q$.
Outline of my answer:
It is obvious that $q\cdot\phi(P)=\phi(q\cdot P)=\phi(\mathcal O)=\mathcal O$, so we know that the order of $\phi(P)$ divides $q$. I can also show that if there exists a $k<q$ with $k\cdot \phi(P)=\mathcal O$, then $\phi(P)=\mathcal O$ using Bezout and the fact that $q$ is a prime.
I am assuming you can somehow proof that $\phi:E[q]\rightarrow E[q]$ is bijective, but I'm failing to do so.

Use the fact that $x \longmapsto x^p$ is a field automorphism of $ \overline{\mathbb{F}}$.

A homomorphism from a finite group to itself is either bijective or it has a non-trivial kernel. Can you exclude the latter alternative?
